# StaggeredList RecyclerView for varying size of Thumbnails

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I'm creating a photo gallery sort of thing and am using RecyclerView for this Staggered List.

**LEFT** one is what **IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE** and the **RIGHT** side shows how **IT LOOKS LIKE RIGHT NOW.**

[image][image]

And this is what my code looks like.

Code where adapter is called:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager lm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
recyclerViewAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(imagesList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

Adapter onCreateViewHolder function:

```
final View itemView;
itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_thumbnail, parent, false);
itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        final int vt = viewType;
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = itemView.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams sglp = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
            switch (vt) {
                case TYPE_LARGE:
                    sglp.setFullSpan(false);
                    sglp.width = 2*(itemView.getWidth());
                    sglp.height = sglp.width;
                    break;
                case TYPE_SMALL:
                    sglp.setFullSpan(false);
                    sglp.width = (itemView.getWidth());
                    sglp.height = sglp.width;
                    break;
            }
            itemView.setLayoutParams(sglp);
            final StaggeredGridLayoutManager lm = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) ((RecyclerView) parent).getLayoutManager();
            lm.invalidateSpanAssignments();
    }
    itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
    return true;
}
});
return new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the right side image, is the bottom middle one 5 or 7?

Comment: Sorry, corrected the image. It is 7.